# IAM user id from AWS signature?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I have configured my api gateway to authorize via IAM and that works just fine. In my backend application (nodejs/elasticbealstalk) I would like to know which user the aws signature belongs to so I can implement conditional logic. Is that possible?

I am aware that I can parse the access token and invoke list users (then iterate until a match if found) using the AWS SDK. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is available in `$context.identity.user` as mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference). You can just pass this in the request payload by using a mapping template or pass it as a parameter as mentioned [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html)